how should i feed the trading view widget with own socket data (datafeed)
I've created a DataFeed class that establishes a WebSocket connection to stream real-time data for use in a TradingView chart. Here's the code for the class:
export default class DataFeed {
  constructor(symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
    this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://socket");
    this.subscribers = {};
    this.pingInterval = null;
    this.socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log("WebSocket connection established");
      this.subscribe(this.symbol, "1m"); // Default to '1m' interval
      this.startPing(); // Start the ping interval
    };
    this.socket.onmessage = (event) => this.onMessage(event);
    this.socket.onerror = (error) => console.error("WebSocket Error:", error);
    this.socket.onclose = () => console.log("WebSocket closed");
  }

  onMessage(event) {
    const message = event?.data;
    if (message.includes("welcome") || message.includes("Welcome")) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      const receivedData = JSON.parse(message);
      this.processData(receivedData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to parse WebSocket message:", message, error);
    }
  }

  subscribe(symbol, resolution) {
    const subscribeMessage = JSON.stringify({
      action: "subscribe",
      channel: `kline_${resolution}`,
      symbol: [`${symbol}_USDT`],
    });
    this.socket.send(subscribeMessage);
  }

  startPing() {
    if (this.pingInterval) {
      clearInterval(this.pingInterval);
    }
    this.pingInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        this.socket.send(
          JSON.stringify({
            action: "ping",
            symbol: [],
            channel: "heartbeat",
          })
        );
      }
    }, 5000);
  }

  processData(message) {
    const { data } = message;
    if (!data || !data.startTime || data === "pong") {
      return;
    }

    const bar = {
      time: new Date(data.startTime).getTime(),
      close: parseFloat(data.closePrice),
      open: parseFloat(data.openPrice),
      high: parseFloat(data.highPrice),
      low: parseFloat(data.lowPrice),
      volume: parseFloat(data.volume),
    };

    console.log("Processed bar data:", bar?.close, bar?.volume);
    // Notify all subscribers about the new bar
    Object.values(this.subscribers).forEach((sub) =>
      sub.forEach((s) => s.callback(bar))
    );
  }

  onReady(callback) {
    callback({
      supported_resolutions: ["1", "5", "15", "30", "60", "D", "W", "M"],
      supports_marks: false,
      supports_timescale_marks: false,
      supports_time: true,
    });
  }

  resolveSymbol(symbolName, onSymbolResolvedCallback, onResolveErrorCallback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      onSymbolResolvedCallback({
        name: symbolName,
        description: symbolName,
        type: "crypto",
        session: "24x7",
        timezone: "Etc/UTC",
        ticker: symbolName,
        minmov: 1,
        pricescale: 100,
        has_intraday: true,
        has_daily: true,
        has_weekly_and_monthly: true,
        supported_resolutions: ["1",
          "3",
          "5",
          "15",
          "30",
          "60",
          "120",
          "240",
          "D",
        ],
        data_status: "streaming",
      });
    }, 0);
  }

  subscribeBars(symbolInfo, resolution, onRealtimeCallback, subscriberUID, onResetCacheNeededCallback) {
    if (!this.subscribers[symbolInfo.ticker]) {
      this.subscribers[symbolInfo.ticker] = [];
    }
    this.subscribers[symbolInfo.ticker].push({ callback: onRealtimeCallback });
    this.subscribe(symbolInfo.ticker, resolution);
  }

  unsubscribeBars(subscriberUID) {
    for (let symbol in this.subscribers) {
      this.subscribers[symbol] = this.subscribers[symbol].filter(
        (sub) => sub.uid !== subscriberUID
      );
    }
  }
}

